# Why "No smoking" works but "Yes smoking" doesn't?

Tags: etymology, adjectives, phrase-usage, language-evolution

*No smoking* is a formula used to indicate smoking is not allowed.

Why can't we use *Yes smoking* to indicate smoking is allowed? (Although, we might use humorously but I've never heard actually.)

---

Unlike *yes*, *no* can also be an adverb of degree and an adjective.

Here is the etymology of the adjective *no* from *OED*:

> Variant of *none adj.* with loss of final *-n*, used originally before consonants except *h*, which ultimately became the standard form of the negative determiner except in archaic or poetic use.

Here is an explanation of the adjective (determiner) *none* from *OED*:

> In later use the form *none* (or *nane*, etc.) occurs mainly before vowels and *h*, and after 1600 is almost entirely supplanted by the reduced form *no (nae*, etc.): exceptions are the phrase none effect and before other (see sense A. 2, where its survival may be due to interpreting *other* as postmodifying a pronominal *none*).

The earliest example where *no* denotes that something is forbidden or unwelcome is from a1625 according to *OED*:

> *Swet.* Mercy yet. *Bond.* No talking: puff, there goes all your pitie.
>
> <sub>J. Fletcher Bonduca iv. iv, in F. Beaumont & J. Fletcher Comedies & Trag. (1647) 65</sub>

*No smoking* is a phrase but can be used as an attributive adjective also.

The earliest example of *No smoking* as a phrase is from 1837 (*OED*):

> No smoking aloud in the cabing [sic]!
>
> <sub>W. G. Clark Ollapodiana xxi, in Knickerbocker Dec. 520</sub>

The earliest example of *No smoking* as an adjective is from 1944 (*OED*):

> I wanted to smoke, but fell asleep before the No Smoking sign was switched off.
>
> <sub>J. Gunther D Day i. 13,</sub>

*[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=no-smoking)* has the following for *no-smoking* (adj.):

> 1905; the sign wording itself is attested by 1817.
>
> Smoking is a vice to [sic] -- and a national one, of such magnitude that railroad corporations throughout all their routes in the United States, have a special command in large letters, conspicuously placed at depots and inside of the cars -- "No smoking allowed here." ["The Sailor's Magazine," December 1840]

---

I've tried to answer my own question and it can be useful for other people but I would like to get some further information on this.

The original sense of the adjective *no* is *not any*. I wonder how it evolved to be used in the phrases like *no smoking, no pets* etc.

Also, "Yes smoking" could be a useful shortcut but didn't become a set phrase. It is related to *yes* not being an adjective but language evolves. It can be explained regarding evolutionary linguistics as well.

I think we will stick to "Smoking allowed" for now.

Comment: "No smoking" can be thought of as short for "There is no smoking allowed here".  One doesn't say, "There is yes smoking here" They say, "Smoking is permitted here" which can be shortened to "Smoking permitted" or "smoking allowed" etc.

Comment: It certainly is a very old way of expressing  e negation or a ban:  ***Construction no X, no Y attested from 1530s (in no peny no pardon)***. No problem as an interjection of assurance first attested 1963. No way as an expression meaning "it can't be done" is attested by 1968 ***(no way "by no means" is from c. 1400)***. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=no

Comment: *no*  in this context means *not any*. It is a determiner: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No

Comment: I think @njzk2 has the correct idea, and the logic oriented answers are missing the point. "No" is quantifying, as in an amount, rather than a boolean true/false. To demonstrate, "All smoking allowed" is similar. Another example, "there are no apples" is fine, but "yes apples" makes no sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*No* as an adjective is used to negate the default state of affirmation.
Negation and affirmation are not perfectly equal opposites: in general, a mentioned thing is presumed to exist or be true unless it is explicitly negated. This is admittedly a convention rather than an underlying natural law, but it's one that goes very deep and crosses many cultures and disciplines.

In logic, for example, the statement

```
NOT x
```

is true if `x` itself is false, and false if `x` is true. The function word `NOT` performs the negation. To create the corresponding affirmative statement, we need no function word, and the statement is simply:

```
x
```

which is true if `x` is true, and false if `x` is false. Likewise, in programming, a code block that begins with

```
if (foo)
```

executes if the variable `foo` evaluates to true, and does not execute if the variable evaluates to false. Affirmation is the default state, so we do not need an additional operator to "toggle" the state to affirmation. If we want the opposite to occur, we must use a negation operator:

```
if (!(foo))
```

where the `!` character serves the same purpose as `NOT`, or as the adjective form of *no*.

So the reason we don't use *yes* as an adjective is because it's not needed: its function is served by the absence of *no*. Now, it's true that a sign that merely says "Smoking" may not be well understood, but that's only because "No Smoking" is not a complete sentence. When we see a "No Smoking" sign, we understand that the message it's really conveying is "No smoking is allowed"--and of course we don't need any form of *yes* to convey the opposite message, "Smoking is allowed."

Comment: I'm not sure I buy this. Consider a place where making a right turn at an intersection when the traffic light is red is forbidden (so "no" is the "default state"). Suppose that there is one intersection in that place where, exceptionally, right turns on red are permitted. Could the intersection be signed "Yes Right Turn On Red"? I don't think so; that sounds incredibly weird to me. (The inverse, "No Right Turn On Red", sounds fine and is in common use across the US. )

Comment: @senshin there is such a place: New York City.  One occasionally sees signs permitting a right turn on a red light; these signs of course do not include the word "yes."

Comment: @senshin I think the problem is with the imperative. When you see "No right turn on left", there is a command not to turn. The yes can be interpreted as a mandatory right turn, not an allowed right turn. The same with the sign. No smoking is an order not to smoke. Yes smoking still depends on or willingness to smoke to have an effect.

Comment: "No Right on Red" only sounds fine in the context, because it is commonplace in the US that right turns on red are explicitly allowed.  The only time I could see "Yes Right on Red" making sense if Right on Red is the default, and the certain stretch of road had multiple signs saying "No Right on Red" preceding it. "Right on Red permitted" would make sense in a context where it would normally not be, such as the UK.

Comment: When I want to show support for what my friend Red has done I sometimes say, "Yes! Right on, Red."

Comment: @Vogie: The specific wording in NYC is "After stop, right turn permitted on red" (after punctuating and correcting for idiosyncratic capitalization).

Comment: @Mindwin _No smoking_ is not an imperative or a command. It is a statement of permission: _No smoking **is allowed**_. The imperative form is _**Don't smoke**_.

Answer (score 8):

We don't see "Yes Smoking" because, where signs are concerned, the opposite of **No smoking** is **Smoking**

[image]

Comment: This seems more like an adjective modifying an assumed noun such as "room" or "cabin."

Comment: why is "wills's gold flake" reversed relative to "smoking"?

Comment: @CupawnTae So those outside know which car to enter, and those inside see the advertisement.

Comment: @Eric - You could say exactly the same about 'No Smoking'.

Comment: @timothymh I guess, I just thought the sign didn't look particularly translucent

Comment: @chasly If the rest of the cars are non-smoking, their No Smoking signs are likely subtler as it's the understood default for the train.

Answer (score 5):

Since your question is basically "Why doesn't *Yes smoking* work?" it is helpful to start with *yes* before moving to *no*.

*Yes* is a particle or an interjection, or a noun directly referring to one of these. As such, it is almost always understood as a one-word sentence.

*No* can be the opposite of *yes*, but it also has other meanings that can't be negated to *yes*. *No* is also a determiner meaning *not any* and *none*. The antonyms of these are *any* and *some*.

#### *No* is also a determiner meaning *not any* and *none*.

> He has **no** apples.
>
> Does he **not** have **any** apples?
>
> How many apples does he have? **None**.

Negating these sentences, thereby making them positive again, gives:

> He has apples.
>
> Does he have **any** apples?
>
> How many apples does he have? **Some**.

So, to negate *No smoking* by adding another word, you could say *Some smoking*, but the most normal way is to simply not negate it in the first place: *Smoking*.

- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yes
- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no